# Custom segue crashes app - "Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged"

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, segue, ios11

First of all, I know there are dozens of questions with the same error message as mine. However, the context of my problem is totally different, so I wasn't able to solve it with the previous StackOverflow questions.

I created a custom Segue and everything worked fine yesterday.
Today, I have modified my app even further and no all of a sudden my app doesn't work anymore.

My app crashes with the following eror message

> Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is
>   discouraged - AppName.MainNavigationController: 0x7ff19f054a00.

The crashing point is: `sourceViewController.present(destinationViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)`

After modifying my app today, I have Following controller hierarchy
     VC:          A -> UINAVIGATION CONTROLLER: B - ROOT CONTROLLER OF NAVIGATIONCONTROLLER: C -> * WITH THIS CUSTOM SEGUE * VC: D

-> : represents a segue. This segue is made from C, the root controller of the navigation Controller

It's really strange because everything was working perfectly and now I get this crash.

This is the perform method of my custom segue:

```
       override func perform() {


    //.... custom segue animation......
    //.....

        UIView.animate(withDuration: DURATION, animations: {

// Some more animations
            self.bubble.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            destinationView?.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            destinationView?.alpha = 1
            destinationView?.center = sourceCenter!
            destinationView?.layer.cornerRadius = 1


        }, completion: { (_) in

            self.bubble.isHidden = true
            destinationView?.clipsToBounds = defaultClipsToBoundsSettings!

            //finally showing it
            DispatchQueue.main.async
                {
//********* THIS IS THE CRASH POINT
                 sourceViewController.present(destinationViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)


            }

        })



    }
```

Here I am performing the segue from my button action method:

```
castedRootController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ViewShare", sender: nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The segue should be between VC A and navigationController B , as the VC C is considered a rootVC for the navigation , Also during the segue VC A is shown no the navigationController

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I have edited my question. I am sending the segue already from the root navigation controller, so it's: 
VC: A -> UINAVIGATION CONTROLLER: B - ROOT CONTROLLER OF NAVIGATIONCONTROLLER: C -> * WITH THIS CUSTOM SEGUE * VC: D

Comment: From the Root controller of the navigation controller (C)

Comment: anything in the middle is presented modally ??

Comment: I mean in viewDidLoad , viewDidAppear ?? , also use self.performSegue as the segue should be done from it's source

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I'm calling it from one of my button action methods.***

Comment: Yes, I did. The strange thing is, everything worked before adding those view controllers.

Comment: navigation controller C should have a root to do the segue from it to D  , or better remove it and do the segue directly from rootVC of navigation controller B to D directtly

Comment: Ok it's working now, but why can't I make custom segue from C?